# Delete photos of a non-member in a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, photos, delete

Artists of Texas has resurrected a neglected group and have found about 30 photos of a non-member that no admin can delete. When clicked on, they take you to this person's Facebook account; when you go to options below the photo, the delete option is not there. We would love to have anyone's suggestion on how to remove these unwanted photos and they are not in an album.

Comment: Was the photo posted directly on the group wall or is the group just tagged/@mentioned in a photo that is posted somewhere else?  It sounds like the group is just tagged if clicking on it takes you elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Is the administrator to the account using Facebook as the account admin (i.e. not their personal account)? I ask because sometimes I don't realize whether I'm still using my personal account when dealing with a page I'm an admin to. It might not be giving permissions to delete the picture/post.

Another suggestion: 
Go to your page (make sure you are using Facebook as the page admin via the top right).

[image]

Then click where it says "See All" under "Recent Posts by Others on [pagename]" (above). A screen like this should pop up (only with your posts on your page).

[image]

My mouse was hovered over the "X" when I took the screenshot, but you can remove the post via this button.

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but I can surely tweak my answer if you have any other problems with it.